# What is the solution for this C compiling error using printf()?

Tags: c

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int M, N, O, P;
    printf("Enter the value of M\n");
    scanf("%d", &M);
    N = 3*M^2;
    O = M + N;
    P = M + M;
    printf("The value of %d \n", M + %d \n", M equals %d \n", P %d \n", N %d \n", O);
    return 0;
}
```

The error:

> test.c: In function 'main': 
> test.c:9: error: expected expression before '%' token 
> test.c:9: error: stray '' in program 
> test.c:9: error: stray '' in program

I can't figure out how to properly print the values of `M`, `N`, `O`, `P` and test alongside with it.

Comment: You need to read the documentation Try a printf tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm

Comment: Just an FYI, I don't think `^` does what you expect (unless you are expecting a bitwise operation......)

Comment: Or read the documentation straight from the horse's mouth: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1 (latest committee draft).

Comment: @IljaEverilä - that's just cruel to a noob ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have mixed up your formatting string, with some %d and \n outside of your quotes.
Try writing your entire formatting string first, then each of the arguments; like so:

```
printf("The value of %d \nM equals %d \nN  %d \n", M, P, 0);
```

Each %d should correspond to the number you want to print from the arguments, given in order.

Answer (score 1):

Your printf should be like that:

```
printf("The value of %d \n equals %d \n %d \n %d \n", M, P, N, O);
```

You can put your message that you want within the double quotes and then you have to think that the %d is like a placeholder for the variables that you want to print.

Comment: That gives you messages in the form of "the value of 5 equals 5 ..."

Comment: @choeger I didn't read what the message was, I just reordered the format specifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Your [printf()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string) statement is syntactically incorrect. You should use one format string followed by the values to be inserted using the format specifiers.

Something like:

```
printf("The value of M + N equals %d\n", M + N);
```

You can either use many format specifiers (the substrings prefixed by a percentage sign) or many printf statements as you wish.

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string) for an explanation.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but, if my memory doesn't deceive me, your original answer did not include the example - SO frowns upon link only answers.